# Как создать блок дугой? (с картинкой - примером)

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, html, clip-path

Как создать блок дугой (внутрь блока) (потратил 5 часов на решение задачи и не нашел ответа).

Пользуюсь `WordPress/css`.

Пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Как один из вариантов:

```css
div {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0 / 100% 100% 0 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: humster_spb,благодарю за ответ,как вариант очень хороший и в решении моей задачи он пригодиться как небольшая часть.

Comment: можешь скинуть инфу по поводу такого решения: `border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0 / 100% 100% 0 0;`? я такого не видел еще)

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, вот тут, например: http://shpargalkablog.ru/2017/08/semicircle.html

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, ещё про бордер-радиус и всякие фигуры тут есть: https://habrahabr.ru/post/141658/

Comment: @СерегаОн, будьте добры, если вам помог чей-то ответ - отметьте его решением, таковы правила SO:)

Answer (score 3):

Это можно сделать на `SVG`:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="230" height="150" viewBox="0 50 230 150" style="border: 1px solid crimson">
  <path style="fill:none;stroke:crimson;stroke-width:3;" d="M 50,131 C 91,86 161,108 165,163"/>
  <polygon points="47 125, 57 135, 47 135" fill="crimson"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Самое первое что нужно это некий блок который перекроет изображение, для этого воспользуемся приблудой из css3 border-radius:16em/1em; смотрим сниппет

```css
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.img {
  width: 640px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.img:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 16em/1em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
}

.img:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 16em/1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
}

.bullet {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0 / 100% 100% 0 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50%;
}

.bullet:before {
  content: "";
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid red;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: -12px;
  top: 50px;
  transform: rotate(-80deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="https://get.wallhere.com/photo/women-model-sitting-black-hair-fashion-hair-Person-swimwear-clothing-supermodel-girl-beauty-woman-lady-leg-1920x1200-px-human-positions-photo-shoot-art-model-abdomen-human-body-thigh-undergarment-590671.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="bullet"></div>
</div>
```

и как видно я вставил изображение в блок который родитель для псевдо элементов, вот псевдо элмементами я задал скругление

Comment: Автор вопроса хотел узнать, как сделать дугу( красную стрелку), как мне кажется, хотя я тоже сомневался, то ли я сделал(вопрос некрасиво сформулирован)

Comment: Я хотел на свг сделать но подумал что ещё потом объяснять надо...и сделал на css

Comment: Ну, не сказал бы:)
Достаточно объяснить, как сделать `path`, а именно через Inkscape, и треугольник через polygon, а там уже координаты x y 3х поинтов(в моём случае конечно)

Comment: если не по теме я ответил могу удалить ...

Comment: Можно ведь дополнить, сделать дугу на том, что у тебя есть и будет полноценный ответ))

Comment: дополнил.......

Comment: Хороший пример!